# Extracting date from SQL String

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a field in my database that contains data like this:

```
'DUES 1/4/2013'
'DUES 2/18/2013'
'DUES 3/25/2013'
...
```

What I want to do is extract the date portion of the string and cast it into a valid SQL Date object. How can I do this? I'm using SQL Server 2000.

Comment: Try `CAST(REPLACE(str, 'DUES ', '') AS DATETIME)`

Comment: @TI -- It throws an error for some reason. Says it can't convert the string to a date.

Comment: @TI -- Specifically "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: @TI -- Nevermind. I had one row that was NULL. Once I excluded NULL rows, it worked!. Thank you!\

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (col VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @temp (col)
    SELECT 'DUES 1/4/2013'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'DUES 2/18/2013'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'DUES 3/25/2013'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL

SELECT 
    [date] = 
        CASE WHEN col IS NOT NULL 
            THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(col, 5, LEN(col)) AS DATETIME) 
        END  
FROM @temp
```

**Results:**

```
date
-----------------------
2013-01-04 00:00:00.000
2013-02-18 00:00:00.000
2013-03-25 00:00:00.000
NULL
```